# How is it possible to use SSH key if I connect to a repository using https?

Tags: git, github, ssh, https

The company firewall does only allow https connection to github.com ( no ssh ), so I added the repository like this:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/myProject.git
```

Unfortunately if I call `git push`, github asks for my username and password. I already created an ssh key using `ssh-keygen`.

How is it possible to use SSH keys with a https repository?

---

I tried [SSh over HTTPS](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/using-ssh-over-the-https-port):

```
ssh -T -p 443 git@ssh.github.com
```

But I get this error:

```
ssh: connect to host ssh.github.com port 443: Connection refused
```

Comment: It is not `SSH over HTTPS` it is `SSH over the HTTPS port`. The protocol is still SSH just the used port changes from 22 to 443.

Answer (score 1):

The error is supposedly because `ssh.github.com` is a dedicated server (I think several of them, and it resolves to the two distinct IP addresses presently), and your company's firewall supposedly only whitelists connections to "basic" `github.com` which resolves to a set of hosts different to those of `ssh.github.com`.
This is needed because in both cases the server-side software handling incoming connections on *the same* port has to be different (an SSH server versus a web server speaking HTTPS).

As to your general question — no, this is not possible: SSH (the **S**ecure **SH**ell protocol and **H**yper**T**ext **T**ransfer **P**rotocol, **S**ecure) bear no relation to each other except for the fact they both provide security (authentication and confidentiality) for the communication channels they manage.

Comment: @iter-ator, if your original problem is the need to type your password each time you access your github repos via HTTPS, you might consider using the Git's "credentials cache" which may be set up to hold your credentials in memory for a configurable amount of time. See `git help credentials`. It's not exactly a solution but is better than nothing. (And with SSH keys you still have to decrypt them when adding them to the SSH agent, which is basically almost the same thing.)